# Cordova Application size huge increase after adding Crosswalk web View plugin [VS 2015]

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, crosswalk-runtime, html-framework-7

I am building a simple cordova app using framework7 in vs community edition 2015, the default app build apk size is around ~ 3 mb, as for using smooth transitions etc. I ended up using crosswalk web view embed, but after embedding the apk size have jumped to ~29 mb in size and no matter i tried  cannot find any solution to it. the official crosswalk library claims a increase of only 15 mb in current size of application, while what i am getting is too much.

Target Device is android. Cordova CLR version is 6.0.0 , target andorid is 4.0+

any help would be much appreciated.
thanks

Comment: If your app doesn't need all of Crosswalk features, you might use the Crosswalk Lite version and get about 12-14MB increase in the APK size.

Comment: hi, i think crosswalk lite is dead and not supported anymore.

Comment: Yes, both Crosswalk and Crosswalk Lite have been discontinued, but they still work well enough to support Android 4.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a blank cordova project and added [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html). Then build it into apk files. I got two output files with plugin: `android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk` : 22.7 mb and `android-x86-release-unsigned.apk`: 26.2 mb. Without plugin : `android-release-unsigned.apk` : 261 kb.

I uncompressed `android-x86-release-unsigned.apk` file and found out that the file `libxwalkcore.so` is significantly huge, almost 50 mb:

ScreenShot:
[image]

So I think you are having the correct output. The downloaded library will give an increase of 22 to 26 mb in size.

> the official crosswalk library claims a increase of only 15 mb in current size of application

It could probably be the result of documentation update's delay. You can report this issue to the CrossWalk official website.